# How to extend tt_address

Tags: typo3, extbase

I created my first extbase extension which works fine. Now i want to enter address informations into my extension, like city, zip code and street.

I preffer to create a relation to "tt_address". My aim is to create a 1:N relation from "tt_address" to my extension.

But the extension "tt_address" is based on "pi_base", how can i handle this issue? How must my "tca" look?

How can i create a record form my "createAction" into the "tt_address" table, should i need the object manager?

Is there a example on web?

**Update**, i extend my model with street, zip and city:

```
   /**
     * street
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $street;

    /**
     * street
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $zip;

    /**
     * street
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $city;

    public function setStreet($street)
    {
        $this->street = $street;
    }

    public function getStreet()
    {
        return $this->street;
    }

    public function setCity($city)
    {
        $this->city = $city;
    }

    public function getCity()
    {
        return $this->city;
    }

    public function setZip($zip)
    {
        $this->zip = $zip;
    }

    public function getZip()
    {
        return $this->zip;
    }
```

After this i extend my typoscript setup.txt

```
plugin.tx_oaevents {
    view {
        templateRootPath = {$plugin.tx_oaevents.view.templateRootPath}
        partialRootPath = {$plugin.tx_oaevents.view.partialRootPath}
        layoutRootPath = {$plugin.tx_oaevents.view.layoutRootPath}
    }
    persistence {
    storagePid = {$plugin.tx_oaevents.persistence.storagePid},148
    classes {
        Mab\Oavents\Domain\Model\Events {
            mapping {
                        tablename = tx_nnaddress_domain_model_address
                        columns {
                            zip.mapOnProperty = zip
                            street.mapOnProperty = street
                            city.mapOnProperty = city
                        }
                    }
        }

    }
}
```

And in last step i extend my extension TCA.

```
address' => array(
            'exclude' => 1,
            'label' => 'Events',
            'config' => array(
                'type' => 'select',
                'foreign_table' => 'tt_address',
                'minitems' => 0,
                'maxitems' => 1,
            ),
        ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a model and map it in TS to table tt_address. In this mapping you need to set each field from your model to a column in table that you want to map. When you will have model and mapping everything else is the same. You create controller and repository for your model and you can create `createAction` that will insert something to table tt_address

Comment: i extend my model and create a typoscript mapping. Also i extend my TCA , is this the correct way? But now i can't see the address relation field in backend on editing my extension record and i don't extended my extesion table with the fields city, zip and street , is this correct?

Comment: I'm not sure you're following me. If you want your model to work on table `tt_address` you need to map it on this table. In your code I can see that you've mapped it to `tx_nnaddress_domain_model_address`. Why ? What are you extending ? You need to create a model of tt_address table. nothing more

Comment: it was an paste error, it's correct i want to extend tt_address. I think i can follow you. To realize a one to many relation i must map uid.tt_address to my extension address column , is this correct? A lot of thanks for your support

Comment: if you want to create relation than yes, you need to map uid of tt_address cause you need to have primary key as uid for mapping